# want to do dispatch.then(...)

Tags: redux, redux-thunk

I use redux, react-redux, react-router, and react-router-redux, and redux-thunk.

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import { routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux'
import  thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'
...    
const reduxRouterMiddleware = routerMiddleware( browserHistory )

const store = createStore(
    mainReducer,
    applyMiddleware(reduxRouterMiddleware, thunkMiddleware)
)
```

I was hoping as a result to be able to do thenable dispatch

```
dispatch(...).then()
```

but I get the message that `then` is not a function of dispatch.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Can you provide the context for your dispatch() call ?

Comment: @HenrikBechmann can you share your solution to your problem?

Comment: @liquidpenguins see https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk

Answer (score 16):

the answer: it depends on what is returned by dispatch; if a promise is returned, then it will be thenable.

Comment: https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-wrapping-dispatch-to-recognize-promises